# ADO.NET transparent broker to separate reads and writes?

Tags: .net, ado.net, master-slave, read-write, broker

I want to separate the database reads and writes my .NET application performs, without modifying the application code.

Is there a commercial or open source product, that would work as a virtual "SQL Server" endpoint, while performing the function of a proxy/broker, talking to the actual SQL Server?

I would then point my application to such a broker by modifying the connection string, and it would then route the reads and the writes to corresponding SQL Server based on its knowledge of ADO.NET or the TDS protocol or something. I know such things exists in Oracle / Java world, but is there something like this in the Microsoft world?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a capability called an "Availability Group Listener" that sounds very similar to what you're looking for here.  It's documented well on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213417.aspx).

Here's an excerpt of the documentation which sounds like the capability you want:

> The primary database of the availability group processes the incoming read-only routing request and attempts to locate an online, read-only replica that is joined to the primary replica and is configured for read-only routing. The client receives back connection information from the primary replica server and connects to the identified read-only replica.

Note that this capability is SQL Server specific, not generically applicable to any ADO.NET provider; since your question mentioned both ADO.NET and SQL Server, I'm not certain this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks, solution being SQL Server specific is acceptable, however, this one requires a read/write selector added to the connection string as "ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly" -- which from the application's perspective is same as directly pointing to a readonly replica. I hoped to find something that does not require specifying the intent on the application side. Thanks for the information anyway.